# Display (error)message in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my self written php framework i have a method to display a simple message:

> $page->displayMessage('Title','Body','error','layout.php');

This loads a view and layout and displays the message in it. I use it for messages for which i dont want to make a new view for.

Now i'm missing this functionality in Zend and want to implement it again but at first i want to ask you guys if there is already something like this in the Zend Framework and i didn't noticed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'body' => 'Team Framework',
    'title' => 'view partials',
    'error'=>'my error')); ?>
```

and inside partial.phtml we have following content

```
<title><?php echo $this->title ?></title>
<body><?php echo $this->body ?>   <?php echo $this->error ?></body>
```

Partial is a view helper . Here $this is an instance of Zend_View . If you want to call this code in controller then use $this->view->partial(); instead

Comment: That's not exactly what i mean, the message should replace the whole content.

Answer (score 1):

Another common method is to throw an exception (assuming you are letting the user know about an error), and using the error handler plugin to catch it, and spit out a friendly version of the message to the user.